# Navigation in date picker to another view

Tags: swiftui

This is my code :

```
 import SwiftUI

 struct Test2: View {
 @State private var selectDate = Date()
    
 var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
           let formatter = DateFormatter()
           formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d"
           return formatter
       }
 var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Text("\(selectDate, formatter: dateFormatter)")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    
            DatePicker(
                   "Start Date",
                   selection: $selectDate,
                   displayedComponents: [.date]
            )
                .accentColor(Color.red)
                .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            
            
           
       }
       }
       }
```

what can I do ? any idea ?

```
   struct Test2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
         static var previews: some View {
        Test2()
             }
          }

   struct Test3: View {
      @Binding private var selectDate = Date()
       var body: some View{
       Text("\(selectDate)")
           }
      }
```

I want once I pick a specific date navigate to Test3 view, any idea how to achieve it ?

and how can I bind the selectedDate from view 2 inside view 3, so it will be displayed in view 3 once navigated ?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `selectedDate` changed with `.onChanged` and then set a var that is triggering a `NavigtionLink` programmatically:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectDate = Date()
    @State private var navigate = false

    var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d"
        return formatter
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                
                Text("\(selectDate, formatter: dateFormatter)")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                DatePicker(
                    "Start Date",
                    selection: $selectDate,
                    displayedComponents: [.date]
                )
                    .accentColor(Color.red)
                    .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                
                    .onChange(of: selectDate) { newValue in
                        navigate = true
                    }

                NavigationLink(isActive: $navigate) {
                    DetailView(selectDate: $selectDate)
                } label: {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var selectDate: Date
    var body: some View{
        Text("\(selectDate)")
    }
}
```

Comment: omg it worked thank you very much ☺️